# Function not found in custom module - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, module, vuejs2, vue-router

I write two functions in a module to use on some sections of an hybrid mobile app. The module name is "functs.js":

```
module.exports = {
    TRUNCATE_LETTERS (txt,max) {
        const limit = max || 15;
        const text = (txt && txt.trim()) ? txt.trim() : '';
        const dots = '...';
        let resp = '';

        if ( txt.length > limit ) 
        {
            resp = txt.substring(0, limit) + ' ' + dots;
        } else {
            resp = text + ' ' + dots;
        }

        return resp;
    },

    TRUNCATE_WORDS (txt,max) {
        const limit = max || 10;
        const text = (txt && txt.trim()) ? txt.trim() : '';
        const dots = '...';
        let resp = '';

        const arr = text ? text.split(' ') : [];
        let newArr = [];

        if ( arr.length > limit ) 
        {
            for ( let i = 0; i < limit; i++ )
            {
                newArr.push( arr[i] );
            }

            resp = newArr.join(' ') + ' ' + dots;
        } else {
            resp = text + ' ' + dots;
        }

        return resp;
    }
}
```

When I call TRUNCATE_LETTERS and comment TRUNCATE_WORDS all goes fine but on uncomment it I get this error on the CLI:

```
warning  in ./src/views/Offers.vue?vue&
type=script&lang=js&

"export 'TRUNCATE_LETTERS' was not found
 in '@/components/functs'
```

I tested the two functions in a separate HTML file and did not receive any errors.

Is there something that I don't saw? I need to truncate for words, not for letters.

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax:

```
module.exports = {
  TRUNCATE_LETTERS: function(txt,max) { ... },
  TRUNCATE_WORDS: function(txt,max) { ... }
}

Use :
    const { TRUNCATE_LETTERS, TRUNCATE_WORDS } = require("/path/mymodule");

    or

    const TRUNCATE_LETTERS = require("/path/mymodule").TRUNCATE_LETTERS ;
```

With export default/import in VueJs :

```
const truncate = {
  TRUNCATE_LETTERS: function(txt,max) { ... },
  TRUNCATE_WORDS: function(txt,max) { ... }
}

export default truncate;

Use:
  import truncate from "/path/mymodule";
  truncate.TRUNCATE_LETTERS(...);

  or

  import { TRUNCATE_LETTERS, TRUNCATE_WORDS } from "/path/mymodule";
```

Comment: After much trial and error (even using your example) I finally preferred to export each function and using "import { TRUNCATE_WORDS, ... } from '@/components/functs'". Now all goes fine. Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Well. Now I get many warnings, including from a new function that I add later:
warning  in ./src/components/nav.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
"export 'RANDOM_ID' was not found in '@/components/functs'

Comment: Sorry, I better stay exporting each function because that way work for me. :-)